# Read file path from Kafka topic and then read file and write to DeltaLake in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have a use case where the file path of the json records stored in s3 are coming as a kafka
message in kafka. I have to process the data using spark structured streaming.

The design which I thought is as follows:

1. In kafka Spark structured streaming, read the message containing the data path.
2. Collect the message record in driver. (Messages are small in sizes)
3. Create the dataframe from the data location.

```scala
kafkaDf.select($"value".cast(StringType))
       .writeStream.foreachBatch((batchDf:DataFrame, batchId:Long) =>  {
  //rough code
  //collect to driver
  val records = batchDf.collect()
  //create dataframe and process
  records foreach((rec: Row) =>{
    println("records:######################", rec.toString())
    val path = rec.getAs[String]("data_path")
    val dfToProcess = spark.read.json(path)
    ....
  })
}
```

I would like to know your views, if this approach is fine? Specifically if there is some problem with creating the Dataframe after calling collect.
If there is any better approach, please let me know the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea works perfectly fine.

Actually, it is mandatory to collect your Dataframe to the driver. Otherwise, you can not create a distributed dataset by calling the SparkSession on each executor. Without the `collect` you will end up having a NullPointerException.

I have slightly re-written your code sceleton and also implemented the part on how to write your Dataframe into a delta table (based on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779016/read-file-path-from-kafka-and-then-read-and-write-to-deltalake)). In addition, I am using a `Dataset[String]` instead of a `Dataframe[Row]` which makes life a bit easier.

Using Spark 3.0.1 with delta-core 0.7.0 works fine. As an example my test file looks like

```
{"a":"foo1","b":"bar1"}
{"a":"foo2","b":"bar2"}
```

I sent the location of that file to a Kafka topic called "test" and applied the following code to parse the file and write its columns (based on a given schema) into a delta table using the code below:

```scala
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("KafkaConsumer")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val jsonSchema = new StructType()
    .add("a", StringType)
    .add("b", StringType)

  val deltaPath = "file:///tmp/spark/delta/test"

  import spark.implicits._
  val kafkaDf = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as data_path")
    .as[String]

  kafkaDf.writeStream.foreachBatch((batchDf:Dataset[String], batchId:Long) => {
    // collect to driver
    val records = batchDf.collect()

    // create dataframe based on file location and process and write to Delta-Lake
    records.foreach((path: String) => {
      val dfToProcess = spark.read.schema(jsonSchema).json(path)
      dfToProcess.show(false) // replace this line with your custom processing logic
      dfToProcess.write.format("delta").save(deltaPath)
    })
  }).start()

  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

The output of the `show` call is as expected:

```
+----+----+
|a   |b   |
+----+----+
|foo1|bar1|
|foo2|bar2|
+----+----+
```

and the data has been written as delta table into the location specified through `deltaPath`

```
/tmp/spark/delta/test$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 3 x x 4096 Jan 20 13:37 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 x x 4096 Jan 20 13:37 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 x x 4096 Jan 20 13:37 _delta_log/
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  595 Jan 20 13:37 part-00000-b6a540ec-7e63-4d68-a09a-405142479cc1-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x   16 Jan 20 13:37 .part-00000-b6a540ec-7e63-4d68-a09a-405142479cc1-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
```

Comment: sorry stack did not allowed to edit the comment.
If you can give your views on resources side of it. I mean as we are essentially creating lots of independent spark jobs inside the streaming micro batch. And it may not run all those in parallel. How are resources shared inside those jobs?
Another that it may produce lags in the Kafka topics, as next trigger will wait for the current to complete.

Comment: It is 3:20 AM now, and I've been looking all over for this answer for hours, clueless why I'm getting a NPE. Thanks!