# It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast

Tags: azure, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to process some events with Spark Structured Streaming.

The incoming events looks like:

Event 1:

| url |
| --- |
| http://first/path/to/read/from... |

Event 2:

| url |
| --- |
| http://second/path/to/read/from... |

And so on.

My goal is to read each of these urls and generate a new DF. So far I've done it with a code like this where I did a `collect()`.

```py
def createDF(url):

    file_url = "abfss://" + container + "@" + az_storage_account + ".dfs.core.windows.net/" + az_storage_folder + "/" + url

    """ Read data """
    binary = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(file_url)
    """ Do other operations """
    ...

    """ save the data """
    # write it into blob again

    return something

def loadData(batchDf, batchId):

    
    """
    batchDf:
        +--------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
        |                body|partition|     offset|sequenceNumber|        enqueuedTime|publisher|partitionKey|          properties|systemProperties|                 url|
        +--------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
        |[{"topic":"/subsc...|        0|30084343744|         55489|2021-03-03 14:21:...|     null|        null|[aeg-event-type -...|              []|http://path...|
        +--------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
    """

    """ Before .... 

    df = batchDf.select("url")
    url = df.collect()

    [createDF(item) for item in url]
    """
    # Now without collect()
    # Select the url field of the df
    url_select_df = batchDf.select("url")

    # Read url value
    result = url_select_df.rdd.map(lambda x: createDF(x.url))
  
query  = df \
    .writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(loadData) \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .queryName("test") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

However, when I want to extract the URL without collect, I get the following error message:

**It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast**.

What could be happening?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're calling `spark.read` inside `foreachBatch`. I think that is not allowed

Comment: Thanks @mck. This means then that I have been able to make it work with ``collect()`` because I call SparkSession in the driver, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the call of `collect` the Dataframe `url_select_df` is distributed across the executors. When you then call `map`, the lambda expression gets executed on the executors. Because the lambda expression is calling `createDF` which is using the SparkContext you get the exception as it is not possible to use the SparkContext on an executor.

It looks like you already figured out the solution which is to `collect` the dataframe to the driver and apply the lambda expression there.

Just make sure that you are not overloading (based on memory) your driver.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation @mike :) I based this solution on one of your answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777481/read-file-path-from-kafka-topic-and-then-read-file-and-write-to-deltalake-in-str