# spark read a file based on value in Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm reading messages from kafka. The messages schema is -

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("file_path", StringType(), True),
    StructField("table_name", StringType(), True),
])
```

For each row in the dataframe that I read, I want to open the file in the specified `file_path`, and write it to a delta lake table with the same name as in the column `table_name`.

So for example if the row in the dataframe is -

```
-------------------------------
|   file_path   | table_name  |
-------------------------------
| /tmp/file.csv |   table_1   |
-------------------------------
```

I want to be able to do -

```py
data = spark.read.csv(df["file_path"])
data.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(df["table_name"])
```

Comment: If your dataframe is not huge, you should `collect` it to a native Python collection and then perform the write option iteratively.

Comment: This answers my question exactly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777481/read-file-path-from-kafka-topic-and-then-read-file-and-write-to-deltalake-in-str/65809786#65809786

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the data stream from kafka, maybe you can try something like this.

```
dataframe.foreach(rowObject =>{
// get row object
// have your logic to read the rowObject(0) which has the file path and write to table rowObject(1) which has table name
data = spark.read.csv(rowObject(0))
data.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("rowObject(1)")
})
```